# change voice modulation in android

Tags: android

I need the change the voice modulation of an audio file, tried whole day with SoundPool but it only changes the playing speed of audio. I want to change the modulation. Need your suggestion, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the accepted answer for [Python Audio Frame Pitch Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326822/python-audio-frame-pitch-change) for a brief explanation of what you need to do. For Java libraries that lets you do FFT / inverse FFT, see e.g. [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) (I haven't used it myself, so I can't provide any help with that part).